# Why are there verbs derived from ходить, but not идти?

Tags: глаголы, словообразование, приставки, глаголы-движения

Despite the fact that both ходить and ехать are imperfective verbs, the verbs formed by adding prefixes to ходить are imperfective, while those formed by adding prefixes to ехать are perfective.

**Question 2:** Why doesn't ходить form perfective verbs when adding prefixes, with the imperfective forms created by adding the same prefix to the iterative/frequentive form of ходить, хаживать?

(It gets even more confusing if one also compares how verbs are formed for возить/везти/носить/нести when adding prefixes, but I will stop here for now.)

Comment: *сходить, уходить (кого-то), походить (чем-то), вы́ходить* are all perfective.

Comment: Походить(чем-то) and выходить --что делать?

Comment: @V.V. *походить ферзём, выходить больную собаку*

Comment: Походить на него лицом, выходить из комнаты.

Comment: @Quassnoi Are some of those homophones with imperfective words? Because I thought I had seen imperfective/perfective pairs сходить/сойти, уходить/уйти, выходить/выйти. What are the imperfective partners of the verbs you listed? Maybe схаживать, ухаживать, похаживать, выхаживать? Also, what is походить? I thought пойти was the perfectivization of ходить.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: yes, there are imperfective *уходить* and *походить* (homophones) and *выходи́ть* (a homograph differing in stress), with completely different meanings, though. *Походить* (perfective) means "to make a move", as in a game of chess. Not all verbs come in pf./impf. pairs in Russian.

Comment: @Quassnoi `Походить (perfective) means "to make a move", as in a game of chess` Oh, no, you're killing me. This word is absolutely inappropriate to use in a chess game.

Comment: @Matt: would _походить королевой_ or _походить турой_ be more appropriate? I'm not a chess guy to be honest!

Comment: @Quassnoi Походить, тура, королева, офицер и пр. - это такой шахматный моветон. Почти то же самое, что заговорить по-русски в салоне Анны Павловны Шерер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of verbs with prefixes derived from **идти**.

> войти, найти, пойти, сойти, прийти, уйти, подойти, etc.

In these verbs "и" changes to -й- and -дт- changes to  original -т- ( The original form was "ити"). There was a form "придти", which is obsolete now and we use прийти instead.

This verb has the form приду (not прийду), придешь, придут in the future tense omitting the letter й. But other verbs войду, пойду, уйду, подойду don't drop it.
In the past tense there is a form шёл, шла, шло, шли and with the corresponding prefixes we have пошёл, сошёл, вышел, перешёл, etc.